# Find element that has not class added on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm loading pages in list index, like for eq(1) load this page for eq(2) load that page, every page has class ".pages i" & different pages have different length of "i", on hover on "i" element I add a class ".hovered". so I want to check on click, if user not hover any "i" element so add a class on it ".invalid" only on that "i" index if all "i" elements has class .hovered then load page.

Currently it is working fine as I want if I do not hover all "i" element it add .invalid class on all "i" that has not .hovered class but then I found a bug in it if I hover any "i" element not remain other "i" from hover & click to load other page it don't work not add ".invalid" class on remaining "i" element that are not hover. I also worked with .not function that is also work as :not working right now.

following is the script to perform on click:

```
$("span.file").eq(1).click(function(){
    var iIndex = $(".pages i").length;
    var hoverIndex = $(".hovered").length;  

    if(!$(".pages i").hasClass('hovered')){
        $(".pages i:not(.hovered)").addClass('invalid');
    }
    else{
        if(iIndex == hoverIndex){
          lifeStream();
          setTimeout(function(){
          $(".main1st").load("projects/projects.php");},1600);                                
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do. I am not sure if your english is bad but I am having trouble understanding what you want to actually do. Can you provide a jsfiddle or this example on a live page?

Comment: Could you show a sample of the HTML, or make a fiddle?